# Unable to execute kitchen create on vagrant(Centos7)

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, centos7, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I am trying to execute kitchen create command on Centos7 but below is the message shown, updated the virtual box location on environment variables but still I have seen the below error, can someone please advise. Thank you.

***Creating...
The Provider 'virtual box' that was requested to back the machine 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system.The reason is shown below:
    Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox!Make sure Virtualbox is properly installed.Vagrant uses the 'VBoxMachine that ships with virtual box and requires this to be available on the path***

Answer (score 0):

This means that either VirtualBox is not installed or not installed correctly. Uninstall and reinstall it.